# No networking from host to docker container

Tags: docker, centos, centos7, docker-network

I have a CentOS 7.2 host running Docker 19.03. All docker containers are in a bridge network (172.18.0.0/16).
From the host I can ping the gateway (172.18.0.1) but not my containers (172.18.0.2 and 172.18.0.3). And from my containers I can also ping the gateway but not my host.

The bridge network has basically the default configuration. But is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Directly contacting the container-private IP addresses usually isn't a best practice.  (The setup you have, calling them from the same native-Linux host, is the only setup where it works.)  It's generally better to call a container via its published ports (`docker run -p` option, Docker Compose `ports:`).

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for your answer, I completely agree with you. I'm not connecting the host to the container (or vise versa), it's just to check if there is any connection. The docker exposed ports are not available to the outside (e.g. host) at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker uses `iptables` and a kernel module called `br_netfilter` to manage inter-container networking. When the Docker daemon starts, it creates a variety of IPTables rules it required to operate. And every time a new container is provisioned additional rules are created and manipulated. If iptables is in a weird state, has been modified by you, or is not installed this could cause your issue.

I mentioned `br_netfilter` above. Operates in a similar way. You can confirm the kernel module is loaded with the `lsmod` command. EG: `lsmod | grep br_netfilter`. If it is not loaded, then you can load it with modprobe. EG: `modprobe br_netfilter`. If it is not available, then the kernel module is not installed in your compiled kernel. If you succeed in running `modprobe` to load the module, then you will need to modify `/etc/modprobe.conf` or drop a file in `/etc/modprobe.d` to ensure persistence of kernel modules between reboots.

Comment: add some log: [root@dms-zookeeper-0005 log]# grep "bridge.ko" messages
Jul 10 05:27:00 dms-zookeeper-0005 dockerd: time="2021-07-10T05:27:00.161061360+08:00" level=warning msg="Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: modprobe: WARNING: Module br_netfilter not found.\ninsmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.62.59.83.h195.x86_64/kernel/net/llc/llc.ko \ninsmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.62.59.83.h195.x86_64/kernel/net/802/stp.ko \ninsmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.62.59.83.h195.x86_64/kernel/net/bridge/bridge.ko \n, error: exit status 1"